# Combine 2 matching duplicate values and add a count, within an array of objects

Tags: javascript, json

I have a previous solution that combined a count, based on a single matching value within an array of objects:

EG:

```
[
    {
        "ui5": "sap.m.Bar",
        "count": 2
    },
    {
        "ui5": "sap.m.Bar",
        "count": 1
    },
    {
        "ui5": "sap.m.Panel",
        "count": 1
    }
]
```

Will become:

```
    [
        {
            "ui5": "sap.m.Bar",
            "count": 3
        },
        {
            "ui5": "sap.m.Panel",
            "count": 1
        }
    ]
```

With the code:

```
var r = {};
myArray.forEach(function (o) {
    r[o.ui5] = (r[o.ui5] || 0) + o.count;
})

var outputArray = Object.keys(r).map(function (k) {
    return { ui5: k, count: r[k] }
});
```

However, I am not sure how to compare a more detailed object, based on two matching values!

EG:

```
    [
        {
            "ui5": "sap.m.Bar",
            "_sMutator": "setCustomHeader",
            "count": 2
        },
        {
            "ui5": "sap.m.Bar",
            "_sMutator": "addContent",
            "count": 1
        },
        {
            "ui5": "sap.m.Bar",
            "_sMutator": "setCustomFooter",
            "count": 3
        },
        {
            "ui5": "sap.m.Bar",
            "_sMutator": "setCustomFooter",
            "count": 1
        }
    ]
```

Will be reduced down to the expected output:

```
    [
        {
            "ui5": "sap.m.Bar",
            "_sMutator": "setCustomHeader",
            "count": 2
        },
        {
            "ui5": "sap.m.Bar",
            "_sMutator": "addContent",
            "count": 1
        },
        {
            "ui5": "sap.m.Bar",
            "_sMutator": "setCustomFooter",
            "count": 4
        }
    ]
```

I don't think I can expand my original logic to account for two matching values? Any help would be appriciated!

Answer (score 0):

You could take an array with wanted keys for grouping and use this array for getting a joined key for the group and for getting an object if no object is assigned to the group property.

```js
const
    data = [{ ui5: "sap.m.Bar", _sMutator: "setCustomHeader", count: 2 }, { ui5: "sap.m.Bar", _sMutator: "addContent", count: 1 }, { ui5: "sap.m.Bar", _sMutator: "setCustomFooter", count: 3 }, { ui5: "sap.m.Bar", _sMutator: "setCustomFooter", count: 1 }],
    keys = ['ui5', '_sMutator'],
    result = Object.values(data
        .reduce((r, o) => {
            const key = keys.map(k => o[k]).join('|');
            r[key] ??= {
                ...Object.fromEntries(keys.map(k => [k, o[k]])), 
                 count: 0
            };
            r[key].count += o.count;
            return r;
        }, {})
    );

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: Fascinating! Amazing, thank you! I have not seen "??=" before - it is counted as an expected expression...

Comment: it is a [logical nullish assignment `??=`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_nullish_assignment)
 ...